# Java : Why exception is not being caught inside the Second Method catch block

Tags: java

I have this method calling the below method , i am purposufully providing a wrong port number for the URL to be connected .
But to my surprise , the exception  produced is   being  caught  in  first Method  catch block
Why it is not being handled inside the executeData Method's catch block ??

```
**1st Method** 
public APIResponse execute(Request request, Class<? extends Response> responseClass) {
        try {
        String xmlResponse = executeData(request);
                  // some code
        return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

            return new Response(ErrorCode.SYSTEM_ERROR);
        }
    }

2nd Method
public String executeData(Request request) throws IOException {
        URL url = null;
        URLConnection urlc = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:80870/");
            urlc = url.openConnection();

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
**// This is not being executed .**
        }

                           // Some code
                   // Some code
        return xmlResponse;
    }
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that nothing in the executeData exception handler throws an exception before you see the results from the code you commented out executing?

Comment: Does it work if you remove `throws IOException` from the second method?

Comment: @Viruzo , doesn't help if i am remove that throws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because your line

```
// some code
```

produces another exception that is caught. Your 2nd method does not throw any exception, I see nothing wrong with that.

```
connection.connect();
```

Will throw the exception.

You could also check for the status:

```
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode != 200) {
    // Not OK.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess exception occured in

> // some code 
>     //some code

after catch block in `executeData`

Comment: why should we bother as it should be handled at earlier catch block only

Comment: Sorry but how could it be handled in earlier catch block if it occured afterwards?! How do you know that exception occured at try block of executeData?

Comment: The issue came becuase i thoought url.openConnection() will give error , but not it gives error at  urlc.getOutputStream() . Anyways thnks for the help .